# How to get list from specific input of numbers (x,y axis)?

Tags: python-3.x, list, input, output, coordinates

```
Input= 2 2 2 1 2 0 1 0 0 0 0 1
```

first number is X coordinate in normal XY axis (not list), second Y coordinate, third X and so on; so from this input it will look like:

```
Y
2    *
1*   *
0* * *
 0 1 2 X
```

(first*: 2,2, second*: 2,1, third*:2,0 - going from right side).

I need to get output which would look like:

```
 output=
[[0,0,1],
 [1,0,1],
 [1,1,1]]
```

So far I tried this, but don't know how to continue:

```
inp=[2,2,2,1,2,0,1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
maxx=0
maxy=0

for i in range(1,len(inp),2): #yaxis
    if inp[i]>maxy:
        maxy=inp[i]
        continue
    else:
        continue

for j in range(0,len(inp),2): #xaxis
    if inp[j]>maxx:
        maxx=inp[j]
        continue
    else:
        continue

part=[]
for i in range(maxy+1):
    part.append([0 for j in range (maxx+1)])
for k in range(0,len(inp),2):
    for j in range(1,len(inp),2):
        for i in range(len(part)):
            part[i][j]=
```

Comment: What did you try so far? What exactly are you having problems with?

Comment: `inp=[2,2,2,1,2,0,1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
maxx=0
maxy=0
for i in range(1,len(inp),2): #yaxis
    if inp[i]>maxy:
        maxy=inp[i]
        continue
    else:
        continue
for j in range(0,len(inp),2): #xaxis
    if inp[j]>maxx:
        maxx=inp[j]
        continue
    else:
        continue
part=[]
for i in range(maxy+1):
    part.append([0 for j in range (maxx+1)])
for k in range(0,len(inp),2):
    for j in range(1,len(inp),2):
        for i in range(len(part)):
            part[i][j]=`

So far I tried this, but don't know how to continue.

Comment: I tried to edit this into your post. Please check if the indentation matches your actual code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
inp = [2,2,2,1,2,0,1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
tuples = [(inp[i], inp[i+1]) for i in range(0, len(inp), 2)]
print(tuples) # [(2, 2), (2, 1), (2, 0), (1, 0), (0, 0), (0, 1)]

# Define the dimensions of the matrix 
max_x_value = max([i[0] for i in tuples])+1
max_y_value = max([i[1] for i in tuples])+1

# Build the matrix - fill all cells with 0 for now
res_matrix = [[0 for _ in range(max_y_value)] for _ in range(max_x_value)]

# Iterate through the tuples and fill the 1's into the matrix
for i in tuples:
    res_matrix[i[0]][i[1]]=1

print(res_matrix) # [[1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1]]

# Rotate the matrix by 90 to get the final answer
res = list(map(list, list(zip(*res_matrix))[::-1]))
print(res) # [[0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1]]
```